# How to Use command Objects in grails controller

Tags: grails, groovy

How to write a method in `controller` which accepts an `Object`(The model is defined in a different `module`(written in `java` and not part of `grails` project), i have a `maven dependency` to this module).
I dont need any validations done on this class.

I have tried.

```
def pushRawData(Application application)
{

}
```

And passed and a json from a REST client.
like

```
{   
    "browserId": "abcd",
     "id": "def",   
     "ipAddress": "192.168.100.130",
     "productType": "ghi",
     "sessionId": "klm" 
}
```

No signature of method: `com.abc.model.Application.validate()` is applicable for argument types:`() values: [] Possible solutions: wait()`

Now I have added a new `Object` called `ApplicationModelObject`, added `@Validateable`
 and added one variable Application.and tried the `REST reques`t. Now it works

Question:

1. Is it necessary for the command Object to be present in the same grails project?
2. Is it necessary for the command Object to be in grails project?
3. Is it necessary for the command Object to be a groovy object?

Comment: Try this ApplicationModelObject extends Application. Mark the child as Validateable. Use child as command object. With Grails 3 you can implmemt Validateable trait instead. *Thumb typed*